# 77062:77062:0921/091821.489365:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1417) Unable to open X display

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My Server CentOS 7.7 is located in HongKong.

I started the minikube success:

```
[dele@att root]$ minikube start --driver=docker --registry-mirror=https://registry-mirror.com
```

when I run dashboard, there get error:

```
[dele@att root]$ minikube dashboard
  verifying dashboard state...
  Launching proxy ...
  verifying proxy state ...
  Opening http://127.0.0.1:38441/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ in your default browser...
START /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable "http://127.0.0.1:38441/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/"
[77062:77062:0921/091821.489365:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1417)] Unable to open X display.
[0921/091821.528962:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://127.0.0.1:38441/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/'

❌  Exiting due to HOST_BROWSER: failed to open browser: exit status 3
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a graphical environment on the server?

Comment: If it's a remote server, you'll need an X server running on your local system (or run a Linux host locally) and to enable ssh X forwarding.  Are you doing both of these things?

Comment: @LielFridman do you mean I need to install a `graphical environment` on the 
remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with `root` user. Can try the solution mentioned in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3269)

Comment: I use the `dele` user, not root, and I just in the /root directory.